# Has anyone involved with Ant-Man said WHO this silhouette belongs to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015

At the end of the film, when Ant-Man (Paul Rudd) finds himself

> in the Quantum Realm, there is a very brief shot of a silhouette reflected in his visor. I believed the silhouette to be confirmation that The Wasp was alive in the quantum realm, but now I'm seeing articles (like [this one](http://moviepilot.com/posts/2015/07/21/did-ant-man-just-tease-marvel-s-most-powerful-character-yet-3399397?lt_source=external,manual)) claiming that this is a nod to Eternity - a character that will likely appear in either *Doctor Strange* or *Guardians of the Galaxy 2*.

Director Peyton Reed has confirmed that the shadowy figure is indeed intentional, but he's not saying who the figure is. **Has Reed or anyone else involved with the film said who the figure is?**

**IMAGE:** For those who can't make out what I'm referring to:

> [image: Shadowy figure in Scott's visor]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, at least not yet.  There was a [Toronto Sun interview](http://www.torontosun.com/2015/07/17/ant-man-director-peyton-reed-reveals-giant-spoilers) with the director, Peyton Reed:

> [K]eep a very sharp eye out when Ant-Man enters the quantum realm. “I would say just watch out for something, maybe in the corner of the frame, something you might see also reflected in Ant-Man’s helmet,” said Reed. “By the time the DVD and Blu-ray come out and you can single-frame it, it’s there.”

That's as specific as I've seen him get.  Other outlets have interviews that contain variations on this theme, he merely confirms that the reflection is a purposeful Easter Egg, but does not discuss what it's a reflection of.

---

In a [Comic Book Resources interview](http://www.comicbookresources.com/article/ant-man-michael-douglas-isnt-signed-for-more-mcu-films-would-like-to-b), Michael Douglas mentions what he'd hope a future film to delve into:

> I think in this one I had to carry a lot of plot and exposition. In the next one, I hope things get a little more bizarre… the Quantum Realm!

But since that future film hasn't been written yet, it's just guesswork at this point.

---

However, Kevin Feige did tell [The Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/features/ant-man-saga-paul-rudd-804566) that the Quantum Realm links not just to the hypothetical *Ant-Man 2: Too Many Ants-Man*, but to things in Phase 3:

> **How does Ant-Man fit into what you call the Phase Three cycle of Marvel movies?**
>
> **FEIGE** It really is the movie that closes out Phase Two. Phase One ended with Avengers. So some people thought that Phase Two would end with an Avengers film. But the truth is, there is so much in Ant-Man: introducing a new hero, introducing a very important part of technology in the Marvel universe, the Pym particles. Ant-Man getting on the Avengers' radar in this film and even – **this is the weirdest part, you shouldn't really talk about it because it won't be apparent for years – but the whole notion of the quantum realm and the whole notion of going to places that are so out there, they are almost mind-bendingly hard to fathom.** It all plays into Phase Three. It became very clear that Ant-Man is the pinnacle and finale of Phase Two and Captain America: Civil War [May 6] is the start of Phase Three.

(emphasis mine)

And back in March 2014, [Feige told Birth Movies Death](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2014/03/13/kevin-feige-explains-how-magic-will-work-in-doctor-strange):

> Are you watching the *Cosmos* series? That’s magic, [the quantum physics]. It’s unbelievable. If somebody knew how to tap into that stuff, what’s the difference between that and magic?
>
> You don’t get into it in *Harry Potter*, but if a scientist went to Hogwarts he’d find out how some of that stuff is happening! We’re not going to spend a lot of time on that, but there will be some of that. And particularly for a character like Strange, who goes from a man of science to a man of faith and who traverses both worlds. And sometimes there won’t be an answer! Sometimes he’ll want an answer - “How is this happening?!” - and nothing.

This suggests that we may see the Quantum Realm again earlier than *Ant-Man 2*, in 2016's *Doctor Strange*.  This provides some fuel for the idea that it could be a cosmic entity's silhouette.

Comment: 3 seconds. You beat me by 3 seconds.

Comment: Indeed, but it took me way longer to integrate the *Doctor Strange* pieces.  Tracking down those quotes took me forever.

Comment: That last paragraph from Feige reminds me of that Wizard in Harry Potter who was reading "A Brief History of Time" while using wandless magic (which is supposedly VERY difficult).

Answer (score 10):

## Yes this was the Wasp i.e Janet

Screen Rant has reported the following from Kevin Feige on this:

> While plenty of fans spotted Wasp's silhouette in Ant-Man, it could have just been a trick of the light. However, Feige confirmed at the Ant-Man and the Wasp junket press conference that Scott did indeed encounter Janet in the Quantum Realm, as a way of setting up the sequel: "In the first film it was, we got a glimpse of it for people who like to go through frame-by-frame, there was a little silhouette of Janet as the Wasp in there, which is a big story element in this movie."
>
> <sub>[Screen Rant, Kevin Feige Confirms Ant-Man Fan Theory That Set Up Sequel](https://screenrant.com/ant-man-wasp-cameo-quantum-realm-confirmed-feige/)</sub>

Which if you've seen *Ant-Man and the Wasp* it makes a lot of sense that this was indeed Janet in his visor.

Answer (score 3):

No, they haven't. You've summed up almost everything we know about the silhouette in your question - that Kevin Fiege has said that the Quantum Realm a nod towards the kind of thing we might see in the upcoming *Doctor Strange* film, and that *Ant-Man* director Peyton Reed has said that the silhoutte is intentional and nothing more.

Fan speculation says that the figure is either The Wasp, or maybe one of the cosmic entities such as Infinity or Eternity.

I'll keep on looking, but for now I don't think that anyone has said anything more.